# How to Recover Mailbox from old NTBackup Exchange Backup File

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, backup-restoration, ntbackup

I have a backup file that was created by NTBackup from which I need to recover a mailbox (preferably in PST format).

Is it possible to extract this from this BKF backup file? We're running Exchange 2007 now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, those old backups backed up the store in its entirety, it didn't do mailbox level backups.  So the only way you can do what you want is to restore the backup to a temporary [virtual] server, then export the mailbox from that server.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange database files are not meant to be directly accessed, so there's no (supported) way to extract mailbox data from them.

There is commercial software available which is capable of reading mailbox data from Exchange databases (and/or backups), but it's usually quite expensive. This is one I've heard of (but which I never actually used): http://www.krollontrack.com/information-management/email-management-for-exchange.

Another possible solution would be to restore the backup to the original Exchange server, but you said you're using Exchange 2007 now, so this means you don't have it anymore. It *is* possible to get an Exchange database mounted under a different server and Active Directory than the one where it was originally created, but it's definitely not a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2003 mailbox stores can't be restored or mounted outside of the AD environment where said Exchange server was installed. If you've got the original Exchange setup log (which is doubtful) you could set up a temporary AD environment and install Exchange based on the information in the log. That would allow you to mount the mailbox store and export the data.

Comment: I would assume that the Exchnage 2007 is still running in the same AD, so restoring a temporary server with Ex2003 should be doable.  But like @Massimo said, it is no trivial task!

Answer (score 0):

To recover and repair Exchange mailboxes.

Read https://techgenix.com/product/shoviv-exchange-recovery-manager/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/513938)